# Opening and scrolling to accordion anchor from fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I am currently working with a fixed navigation that i am trying to use to control the accordions below it.

what I am trying to achieve is for when the link in the navigation is clicked it will scroll to that section where the accordion is and opens the accordion while giving it the class .open (making it active essentially) .

when another link is clicked the previous accordion then closes and the new accordion opens (while placing the content at the top of the browser window)

currently i have set up where the the fixed navigation scrolls to the correct location (almost - position is not aligned properly when one opens and another closes if an accordion has more content then another)

I created and awful script to open and close the accordions on click of nav link however its very bulky and inefficient:

```
$(function() {
    $('.history').click(function() {
        $(".submenu").eq(1).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(2).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(3).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(4).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(5).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $('.submenu').eq(0).parent().toggleClass('open');
        $('.submenu').eq(0).slideToggle();
    });
    $('.details').click(function() {
        $(".submenu").eq(0).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(2).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(3).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(4).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(5).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $('.submenu').eq(1).parent().toggleClass('open');
        $('.submenu').eq(1).slideToggle();
    });
    $('.school').click(function() {
        $(".submenu").eq(0).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(1).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(3).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(4).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(5).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $('.submenu').eq(2).slideToggle();
        $('.submenu').eq(2).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
    $('.community').click(function() {
        $(".submenu").eq(0).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(1).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(2).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(4).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(5).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $('.submenu').eq(3).slideToggle();
        $('.submenu').eq(3).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
    $('.sold').click(function() {
        $(".submenu").eq(0).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(1).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(2).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(3).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(5).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $('.submenu').eq(4).slideToggle();
        $('.submenu').eq(4).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
    $('.active').click(function() {
        $(".submenu").eq(0).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(1).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(2).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(3).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $(".submenu").eq(4).not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
        $('.submenu').eq(5).slideToggle();
        $('.submenu').eq(5).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

here is my current code: http://codepen.io/algib/pen/QbxPKG

any help or guidance with proper opening and closing of my accordions, and with making sure accordion content is visible at the top when opening and closing.

Answer (score 0):

First let's make sure I understand you correctly: *you want to open the accordion entry that is represented by the navigation entry that is clicked and you want to scroll it to the top.* Right?

The approach (to make it as browser-friendly as possible) would be to leverage the `location.hash`. I made you a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/652bz5on/) as `hashchange` seems to work not properly from within stackoverflow fiddles atm.

The JavaScript part (vanilla js, you can replace the querySelector with `$` if you want) is simply

```js
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange
// gives you a polyfill if you need it.
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(event) {
  [].forEach.call(sections, function(element) {
    element.classList.remove('active');
  }); 
  document.getElementById(location.hash.substring(1)).classList.add('active');
});
```

with the html being

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#a-section">the nav entry for section a</a>
</nav>
<article><!-- the accordion, can be any block -->
  <section id="a-section">
    <header><h1><a href="#a-section">section header, always visible</a></h1></header>
    <p>anything else only visible if section has <code>class="active"</code></p>
  </section>
</article>
```

*Edit:* I forgot to copy the necessary css. My bad.

```css
section > * { display: none; }
section.active > *,
section > header { display: block; }
```